# Notification icon not displayed in samsung Android 7

Tags: notifications, material-design, samsung-mobile, android-7.0-nougat

I am trying to display notification icon for my app. For all the OS versions and devices it is working fine except Samsung devices with Android 7.

[image]

Notification icon in status bar.
[image]

Here is the actual notification icon i am displaying.
[image]

Icon is fully white and transparent in middle, so not visible here.

Here is the code I am using to display icon.

```
Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_comment)
                        .setContentTitle(messageMap.get(MESSAGE_KEY_NOTIFICATION))
                        .setSubText(getTitle(eventType))
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_blue))
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(getPendingIntent(eventType))
                        .setGroup(GROUP_ID_TEAM_INVITATION);
```

Comment: Click on icon image to view it.

Comment: And why do you censor the notification? **It can be easily seen even if you censor it!!**

Answer (score 0):

It was the icon which was causing the issue. Icon was not in proper required size.